# Centering text in a circlular <li>

Tags: css

I have this: `<li>+</li>` and I'm trying to centre the text. For horizontal centering I am using line-height. How can I do the vertical centering with CSS?

Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/d7pXt/

Comment: `text-align: center` gets it pretty close for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use `text-align:center`

Answer (score 2):

`text-align: center;`

Looks like you figured out the more complicated part first, CSS makes it very easy to do this.

Answer (score 2):

[use `text-align:center;`](http://jsfiddle.net/A8y6r/)

```
li {
    background-color: #EEE;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 42px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    list-style: none;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 175px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing horizontal and vertical.  You have the vertical working, for horizontal, just use:

```
text-align: center
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `text-align:center;` to your class:

```
li {
background-color:#eee;
font-size:50px;
line-height:42px;
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
list-style:none;
width:48px;
height:48px;
border-radius:175px;
margin:20px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/d7pXt/5/).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer would be `text-align:center`.

http://jsfiddle.net/d7pXt/6/

Answer (score 1):

> For horizontal centering I am using line-height. How can I do the vertical centering with CSS?

You have those backwards. Vertical centering would be handled by line-height. You can center them horizontally by using `text-align: center`.

[See the updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/d7pXt/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use some `padding`.

`padding:0 0 0 15px;`

Note: this does change the shape slightly.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/d7pXt/7/